# wordpress mysql_num_rows query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am running the following query on a wordpress install to count how many posts have the same title in a certain post_type in the database.

When i echo $title this displays the correct information, and pulls in all the posts with the same title.

But in the query below, the output says "0 Rows" although there are posts existing.

Does everything seem ok in the query below, or am i missing something?

```
<?php

$title = get_the_title();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title='$title'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the query as:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title='".$title."'";
```

I would also recommend you use PHP PDO rather than the mysql_ functions

Comment: It could be that there are no rows... or maybe title has some whitespace before or after it. Try echo $query; and see what it prints out like

Comment: there are definitely rows as mentioned above i echo out the title and they are displayed

Comment: Could you paste the $query string after it's echoed?

Answer (score 0):

I found that get_the_title(); didnt actually work and instead i had to get the post id and then the title from the post id using the following:

```
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
```

the result being:

```
<?php

$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='bookings' AND post_title='".$title."'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
```

Thanks for all the help guys!